# LINQ Select Distinct Count in Lambda form

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, distinct

Given a linq expression of an object collection 'items' such as this:

```
var total = (from item in items select item.Value).Distinct().Count()
```

Is it possible to convert this to use linq functions/lambdas:

```
items.Select(???).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: or just `items.GroupBy(p => p.Value).Count()`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use this:

```
items.Select(i => i.Value).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: Thanks - don't know how I didn't try that!

Answer (score 11):

It must be possible, since behind the scenes, LINQ is translated to lambdas and expression trees (at least LINQ to objects)

In your case the `???` part would be `item => item.Value`, i.e. for `item`, output `item.value`.
So, the whole expression will be

```
var total = items.Select(item => item.Value).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for the description, afraid Daniel beat you to the answer though!