# How to get the count of the values that are repeated in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to find the no of integers that are repeated using linq query. for eg my list consists of

`var array = new int[]{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,16,16}`;

Now i want to query like i want to get the count of `1` as `3`
                                           count of `2` as `4`
                                           count of `3` as `2`
                                           count of `9` as `2`
                                           count of `16` as `2`

How can i do that using linq in c#.
Hope you understand my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609916/linq-select-distinct-count-in-lambda-form

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy, using LINQ's `GroupBy`

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 9, 9, 16, 16 }; 

var counts = numbers
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(grp => new { Number = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() });
```

Result:

```
Number    Count
1         3 
2         4 
3         2 
9         2 
16        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.GroupBy(x => x)
     .Select(g => new {
                       Val = x.Key,
                       Cnt = x.Count()
                      }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` then `Count` on each group:

```
var dic = array.GroupBy(x => x)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

In here, `ToDictionary` is used so you can access to `Dictionary` get `Count` with better performance if you have large list and need to access often:

```
int count1 = dic[1]; //count of 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GroupBy` + `Count`

```
var groups = array.GroupBy(i => i);

foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0} Count:{1}", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
var NumArray= new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 9, 9, 16, 16 };
var counts = NumArray.GroupBy(item => item)
                     .Select(a=>new {Number=a.Key,Count =a.Count()});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new int[] {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,16,16}; 

var query = from x in array
            group x by x into g
            orderby count descending
            let count = g.Count()
            select new {Value = g.Key, Count = count};

foreach (var i in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + i.Value + " Count: " + i.Count);
}
```

Result will be;

```
Value: 1 Count: 3
Value: 2 Count: 4
Value: 3 Count: 2
Value: 9 Count: 2
Value: 16 Count: 2
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/pFqRSd).